# Pass live data from external script to django view

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates

I have a Django project where I want to display live data from devices that are being pinged every 20 seconds. I wrote an external Python script to ping the devices every 20 seconds by running in the cmd `python manage.py ping`.

My problem is I'm not quite sure how I would approach this. Would I pass the returned data from my external script to a view function then send it from there to the client?

Here is the script I wrote that will ping the device and get the values

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusException, ConnectionException, ParameterException
from models import *
from devices_models import *
from views import reciever
import datetime
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
import threading
import time

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        timerThread = threading.Thread(target=run)
        timerThread.start()

def run():
    next_call = time.time()

    while True:
        print("sending ping..")
        with open("test.txt", "a") as my_file:
            for device in TDevices.objects.all():
                if device.bIsLogging == True:
                    my_file.write("Pinging device: " + device.asDeviceName + " at " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + '\n')
                    try:
                        config = TModbusConfigs.objects.get(pk=device.ixDevice)
                        client = None
                        if config != None:
                            client = ModbusTcpClient(config.asIPAddressv4, config.iPort)
                            client.connect()
                            response = None

                            my_file.write("\t(dev ID=" + str(device.ixDevice) + ") pinging registers...\n")

                            for register in TDeviceMeasurememts.objects.filter(ixDevice=device.ixDevice):

                                #determine register type by prefix
                                reg_parse = AddressParser(register.iAddress)
                                func_code = reg_parse.get_prefix()
                                reg_addr = reg_parse.get_address()
                                if func_code == 1:
                                    try:
                                        response = client.read_coils(reg_addr, register.iLength, unit=int(config.iSlaveID))
                                        if response != None:
                                            temp = response.bits[0]
                                        else:
                                            raise ParameterException()
                                    except ConnectionException as ex:
                                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ParameterException() as ex:
                                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ModbusException as ex:
                                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass


                                elif func_code == 2:
                                    try:
                                        response = client.read_discrete_inputs(reg_addr, register.iLength, unit=int(config.iSlaveID))
                                        if response != None:
                                            temp = response.bits[0]
                                        else:
                                            raise ParameterException()

                                    except ConnectionException as ex:
                                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ParameterException() as ex:
                                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ModbusException as ex:
                                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass

                                elif func_code == 3:
                                    try:
                                        response = client.read_holding_registers(reg_addr, register.iLength, unit=int(config.iSlaveID))
                                        if response != None:
                                            if hasattr(response, 'registers'):
                                                value = ''
                                                for val in response.registers:
                                                    value += str(val)
                                                if value != None:
                                                    temp = value
                                            
                                                    my_file.write("\t\t\t" + device.asDeviceName + " (" + register.asInputID + ") Register(" + str(register.iAddress) + "): " + value + "\n")
                                            else:
                                                my_file.write("\t\t\tNo register Attribute \n")
                                        else:
                                            raise ParameterException("Invalid Parameter")

                                    except ConnectionException as ex:
                                        my_file.write("\t\t\tConnectedException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                                        #LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ParameterException() as ex:
                                        my_file.write("\t\t\tParameterException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                                        #LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ModbusException as ex:
                                        my_file.write("\t\t\tModbusException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                                        #LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass

                                elif func_code == 4:
                                    try:
                                        response = client.read_input_registers(reg_addr, register.iLength, unit=int(config.iSlaveID))
                                        if response != None:
                                            if hasattr(response, 'registers'):
                                                value = ''
                                                for val in response.registers:
                                                    value += str(val)
                                                if value != None:
                                                    temp = value
                                                    my_file.write("(" + device.asDeviceName + ") Register( " + str(register.iAddress) + "): " + value)
                                        else:
                                            raise ParameterException()

                                    except ConnectionException as ex:
                                        my_file.write("\t\t\ConnectionException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                                        #LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ParameterException() as ex:
                                        my_file.write("\t\t\ParameterException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                                        #LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass
                                    except ModbusException as ex:
                                        my_file.write("\t\t\ModbusException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                                        #LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                                        pass


                            client.close()

                    except ModbusException as ex:
                        my_file.write("\t\t\ModbusException: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                        if client != None:
                            client.close()
                        #log_exception(ex)
                        LogSysAlert(ex, "Communication")
                        pass
                    except AttributeError as ex:
                        my_file.write("\t\t\AttributeError: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                        if client != None:
                            client.close()
                        pass
                    except Exception as ex:
                        my_file.write("\t\t\Exception: " + ex.message + " - " + ex.string + "\n")
                        if client != None:
                            client.close()
                        pass
                        #raise Exception(ex)

            my_file.write("...-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ending\n\n\n")
            print("finished...")

            next_call = next_call + 20
            time.sleep(next_call - time.time())

class AddressParser():
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address
        self.prefix = None

    def get_prefix(self):
        self.prefix = str(self.address)[0]
        return int(self.prefix)

    def get_address(self):
        if self.prefix != None:
            return int(str(self.address)[1:])
```

right now I only have it writing to a text file but will be converted to an array or objects.

This is my view where I display the devices along with their registers:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def devices(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    devices = TDevices.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        for device in devices:
            if "device_" + str(device.ixDevice) in request.POST:
                device.bIsLogging = True
                device.save()
            else:
                device.bIsLogging = False
                device.save()

    

    return render(request, 'devices.html' , context_instance = RequestContext(request, { 'title':'Device Management', 'sysalerts': TSystemAlerts.objects.all(), 'devices': TDevices.objects.all(), 'counterCheck':  [4,7,10,13,16,19,22]}))
```

One method I can think of is temporarily storing that data somewhere then just have the client ajax `GET` every 20 seconds and read/return that value.

Comment: This seems a bit backwards to me, can you not let the device ping the server (not the other way round)?

Comment: what do you mean have the device ping the server? the device is just a meter somewhere which I'm using my script to send read requests using pymodbus. Don't think the device can do anything but reply to requests I send. Unless I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: I mean let the device post a request to the server, I'd imagine if it can respond to one it must be able to send one also, but then I don't know any of the intrinsics involved

Answer (score 1):

You want to move all that code after `for device in TDevices.objects.all():` from your command and make it a method of the TDevices model.  so something like

```
class TDevices(...):
    [...]
    def ping(self):
         if device.bIsLogging == True:
                # collect data, etc
         return dataDict
```

Then the view calls `device.ping()` and synthesizes the returned data into the view. Sorry if it's a little bit abstract, but the issue is really just where to put your code.  Once it's in the model it's easy for the view to access it. Hopefully you get the gist of it.

Comment: actually this is pretty good. I'm assuming this could still work with my threading.timer?

Comment: It's just python code so anything should work.  At worst you'll have to block for the process to complete.  As long as you're using a multi-threaded web server to serve the pages that shouldn't be an issue unless the process takes a long times and end uses get unhappy.